# Windows Phone 8.0 Blob to Image

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a Web service which is connected to a DB, I need to pull out a type BLOB from that BD through the web service and then create an Image. The web service send a bytes array from the blob and I tried with a converter bind to the image in XML (like some suggestions I found) like this

```
 using (Stream ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length))
        {  
            ms.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            ////////////////Exception here
            bitmapImage.SetSource(ms);
            return bitmapImage;
        }
```

But then I get this error (Exception from `HRESULT: 0x88982F50`). Then I found that maybe could be the format of the array of bytes the problem, that maybe could be in `base64` so I've changed the web service and now it sends me an 64-Base String and then changed to the array of bytes, but still with the same error.

I found [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/544477e9-3785-4c20-a3b1-8492583b9f62/exception-from-hresult-0x88982f50-when-converting-a-base64-string-to-a-bitmapimage?forum=wpdevelop) but still no luck. Then I've found a lot of solutions like `InMemoryRandomAccessStream` or `Image.FromStream` but those solutions are for WP 8.1

Also I used:

```
    image.SaveJpeg(stream, image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight, 0, 90);
    ///////AND////////
    image = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(ms);
```

but still no luck

I'm sure that I'm missing something because every solution point out to these solutions but I really can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get it, it was a error with the DB actually. The data on the column I was getting the array of bytes was corrupt or has another use that I don't understand, so I contact with the DB administrator and he helped me with that so now I have the correct data. the first code really works. Thanks to everyone for the help

Answer (score 0):

I accomplish this (loading a binary object from database into an image) using the following function:

```
public static BitmapImage LoadImage(byte[] imageData)
{
    if (imageData == null || imageData.Length == 0) return null;
    var image = new BitmapImage();
    using (var mem = new MemoryStream(imageData))
    {
        mem.Position = 0;
        image.BeginInit();
        image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        image.UriSource = null;
        image.StreamSource = mem;
        image.EndInit();
    }
    image.Freeze();
    return image;
}
```

As you can see, the function takes a `byte[]` array as a parameter.  I get this array from the database like this:

```
using (var reader = dataLayer.ExecuteReader(sqlString))
{
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader["ImageData"] != null && reader["ImageData"] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            imageBytes = (byte[])reader["ImageData"];
        }
    }
}
```

where `ImageData` is the column name from the database.  The `LoadImage()` function is then called with the `imageBytes` passed in as a parameter.

Comment: I can't use all of these methods of BitmapImage maybe is not supported for the WP.                              `image.BeginInit();
 image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
 image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
 image.UriSource = null;
 image.StreamSource = mem;
 image.EndInit();`

Comment: What errors do you get?  You may need to add `using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;` to the top of the file that you're referencing `BitmapImage` in.

Comment: I already added `using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;` to use BitmapImage class. The error I get is `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage does not contain a definition for BeginInit and not extension method BeginInit accepting a firts argument of type System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage could be found`

Comment: You may be correct then about WP8 not supporting those methods.  I know that they are supported in .NET 4.5, but other than that I am not sure.